# For method of undetermined coefficients, what is the forcing term for a differential term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a differential equation I am trying to solve and I have been trying to find a way to solve it using undetermined coefficients so as to find a homogenous solution and non homogeneous solution. Then I would add the results. For example, there is the following:

$\frac{d y(t)}{d t} + y(t) = \frac{d x(t)}{d t} - x(t)$ where $y(0)=1$ and $x(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$ and $x(t)=t$ for all $t > 0$

I tried ridding the RHS by setting it to $0$ so as to find the homogeneous solution. Then I found $y_h(t)$. However, I'm stuck when it comes to finding a forcing term to find the particular solution, $y_p(t)$, such that it can take the place of the right hand side. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the values of $x(t)$ for $t\ge 0$? If not, then I don't know how you would find $y$.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier Yes, $x(t)$ for $t >= 0$ is just t.

Answer (score 1):

So, we have  nondifferentiable $x$, $$x(t) = \begin{cases} t,\quad t\ge 0,\\ 0,\quad t<0 \end{cases}$$ 
but its derivative appears on the right. This looks somewhat problematic, but it really isn't, and a change of dependent variable clears things up. Let's write $y=x+u$ where $u$ is the new unknown function to be found. The equation becomes $u'+u+x = -x$, or $u'+u=-2x$. A standard way to handle this is using the integrating factor, which is $e^{\int 1\,dt} = e^ t$. So, 
$$(e^t u)' = -2xe^t$$ 
which is solved by integration. Be careful when integrating the piecewise function on the right: make sure the both pieces of the antiderivative agree at $t=0$.

Comment: I'm ultimately sorry, $x(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$. Such a horrible typo.

Comment: @EECSMajor90 When you find a typo in your question, please *edit* the question to make it right. People should not have to look for errata list in comments. You should include both the correction and the fact that $x(t)=t$ for $t\ge 0$. I edited my answer.

Comment: Why did you make a substitution such that $y(t) = u(t) + x(t)$? Is it because there is an arbitrary independent helper variable $u(t)$ such that the sum of such a variable and the known independent variable, $x(t)$, must equal $y(t)$ for the given constraints? Just wanted to understand why you did that.

Comment: @EECSMajor90 I did not like having that $dx/dt$ in the equation, and saw the opportunity to get rid of it. It's a common theme in ODE: absorb terms into others if possible. The integrating factor trick is also kind of like that, turning a sum of two things into one $(e^t u)'$.